# FireDAC how connect to Firebird

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe3, firedac

We want to migrate BDE Database to FireBird embedded in DELPHI XE3. After installing FireDAC I couldn't establish connection to Firebird from FireDAC.In DriverID combobox list of FireDAC connection Editor there is no FireBird driver.
According to Configuring Drivers (FireDAC) at [docwiki.embarcadero.com](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Configuring_Drivers_%28FireDAC%29) information about drivers should be in FDDrivers.ini file, but I couldn't find this file on C: and on D: drives. So, I've created FDDrivers.ini with

```
[FB21_Embedded]
; FB21_Embedded virtual driver will use specified Firebird client library
BaseDriverID=FB
VendorLib=fbembed.dll
```

in application folder, then in c:\windows folder no result.

All is OK with connections from FireDAC to Access and to MSSQL.

How can I connect to FireBird Embedded from FireDAC Delphi XE3?

Comment: Probably - if you only need runtime connection, not designtime - you can make a self-contained application without external ini files. See the documentation of using Firebird. http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/Firebird_and_Interbase_Servers_Questions.html

Answer (score 2):

For XE3 there is no specific Firebird Driver

you have to set with IB Driver

```
[FB21]
; FB21 virtual driver will use specified Firebird client library
BaseDriverID=IB
VendorLibWin32=C:\ib\fb21\bin\fbclient.dll
VendorLibWin64=C:\ib\fb21_64\bin\fbclient.dll

[FB21_Embedded]
; FB21_Embedded virtual driver will use specified Firebird client library
BaseDriverID=IB
VendorLib=C:\ib\fb21_embed\bin\fbembed.dll
```

Comment: So, you mean that [`all the examples`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Connect_to_Firebird_(FireDAC)#Usage_Cases) in docs are wrong ?

Comment: No it's example for XE5 and FireDac for XE5 change

Comment: It's really example for XE5, as ini file Format created by DelphiXE3 menu's Firedac->Explorer differs from ini file format in the example (DriverId instead of BaseDriverID).

Comment: Trying to set Connected property of TADConnection component to true I receive the following error message:"[FireDAC][Phys][IB]product INTERBASE is not licensed". Is it necessary to have licensed INTERBASE to connect to Firebird? if yes, is there any other way to connect to Firebird from DelphiXE3?

Comment: @TLama perhaps for XE3 the proper links would be somewhere near http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/Firebird_and_Interbase_Servers_Questions.html

Comment: @Arioch, you're right! I missed that I linked docs for Delphi XE5 before.